# How to map different port for webpack-dev-server in docker

Tags: docker, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

I've managed to run webpack-dev-server inside a docker container.

`docker run -p 9000:9000 --other-arguments-such-as-volume-mounting-etc my-image`

The webpack-dev-server starts up inside the container and a browser visit looks like this:

```
browser  --[visits]-->  host:9000  --[map]-->  container:9000 
                                               (webpack-dev-server is listening here)
```

Then, webpack-dev-server responds a page with a socket configured to connect to `hostname:9000` for update messages and finally, the browser displays the page. Perfect!

However, if I run the docker container with a different port mapping things goes wrong.

Suppose that I run the container with `-p 9001:9000` and browser visits `localhost:9001`.

```
browser  --[visits]-->  host:9001  --[map]-->  container:9000
                               ^
                       note the difference here
```

A same page would be served from the container and be rendered on the browser. BUT, because the page is exactly the same, the socket code in the page would attempt to connect to `hostname:9000`, where the port number 9000 is configured inside the container as a webpack-dev-server configuration, and then inevitably fail.

```
socket code ----> host:9000 --X--> no where
```

Since this failure only happens when the port-mapping is mismatched, I can avoid this by restricting the port-mapping. But this is a very strict constraint that I don't really want to stand with. I may want to run two instances of that image at same time every now and then and this constraint would lead to port conflict as the port number exposed by the contaienr is fixed at build time.

Is there any way to tackle this?

I'm considering to expose a range of ports at build time. Does that make sense?

Comment: `-p 9000:9001` and then localhost:9001

Comment: @JosefKorbel I'm afraid that is not a valid configuration. The image only exposes `9000` and passing `9000:9001` as port map will goes no where